# How do I set Enum index between 2 value

Tags: c#, enums

I have a requirement to create an Enum like this:

```
Batch.Status:
0 - Batch is Open
8 - Batch is Blind Closed
Else – Batch is Closed
```

I tried to create an Enum Status:

```
public enum Status
    {
        BatchIsOpen = 0,
        BatchIsClosed ,//= 1
        BatchIsBlindClose = 8,
        //BatchIsClosed //= 9
    }
```

But as you can see it not match requirement that BatchIsClosed is else case of 0 and 8. How do I handle it with Enum?
Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible to assign multiple values to enum elements. Instead of that, you can use `Dictionary`.

Comment: Maybe you can create a method that checks the Batch.Status? If you do, you don't need to have enum ranges!